# Converting multiple xlsl files to xls (97-2003 Worksheet) extension without changing the names

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through all the 'xlsx' files in a folder and convert them to 'xls' ( Excel 97-2003 Worksheet) format. I use the following codes but then the output files are still saved as 'xlsx' instead of 'xls'. I am a beginner and looking to learn more from others. Thanks for your help!

```vb
Sub Convert()

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strfilenew As String
Dim xWbk As Workbook
Dim xSFD, xRFD As FileDialog
Dim xSPath As String
Dim xRPath As String

Set xSFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With xSFD
.Title = "Please select the folder contains the xls files:"
.InitialFileName = "C:\"
End With

If xSFD.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

xSPath = xSFD.SelectedItems.Item(1)

Set xRFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With xRFD
.Title = "Please select a folder for outputting the new files:"
.InitialFileName = "C:\"
End With

If xRFD.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

xRPath = xRFD.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"

strPath = xSPath & "\"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")
strfilenew = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Do While strFile <> ""

If Right(strFile, 4) = "xlsx" Then
Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strfilenew)
xWbk.SaveAs Filename:=xRPath & strfilenew, _
FileFormat:=xlExcel18
xWbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
End If

strFile = Dir
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The file format for XLS files is `Excel8`, not `Excel18` - 8 instead of 18.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I changed it to Excel8 and re run but still no luck.

Comment: Try using the numeric constant when saving the file: `xWbk.SaveAs Filename := xRPath & strfilenew, FileFormat := 52` . See https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bit of a mix-up in your file naming, basically as evidenced by the several double-declarations that I removed. The really big mistake was here, `Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strfilenew)` where you tried to open the old workbook by the new name. I think the confusion started here `"Please select the folder contains the xls files:"`. Of course, this is the folder with the XLSX files. The recommended antidote is to use "meaningful" variable names but you chose to speak in riddles (like `xSFD`) which makes coding more difficult.

However, the code below is largely yours, and it does work.

```
Sub Convert()
    ' 230

    Dim Spath           As String               ' path to read from (XLSX files)
    Dim Rpath           As String               ' path to write to (XLS files)
    Dim strFile         As String               ' loop variable: current file name
    Dim Wbk             As Workbook             ' loop object: current workbook(strFile)
    Dim Sp()            As String               ' split array of strFile
    Dim strFileNew      As String
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Please select the folder contains the XLSX files:"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        Spath = .SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    End With
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Please select a folder for outputting the new files:"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        Rpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    End With
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    
    strFile = Dir(Spath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        If Right(strFile, 4) = "xlsx" Then
            Sp = Split(strFile, ".")
            Sp(UBound(Sp)) = "xls"
            strFileNew = Join(Sp, ".")
            Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Spath & strFile)
            Wbk.SaveAs Filename:=Rpath & strFileNew, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
            Wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Observe that the new file name is created by splitting the old name on periods, changing the last element, and reassembling the modified array.

Comment: Omg, it is perfect! That makes more sense to me now. Really appreciate your help Variatus!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm glad the solution worked for you. Please mark it as "selected". Thank you.